# MS ACCESS SQL Join Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vba, left-join

I can get this query to run if I remove the Join, but once I add the join, I get the following error:

Run-Time error '3135': Syntax error in Join Operation

```
sourceDB = "C:\sourcedb.accdb"

SQL = "SELECT e1.lid " & _
        "FROM (eventlog e1 IN  '" & sourceDB & "'" & _
        "LEFT JOIN eventlog e2 ON e2.lid = e1.lid)"
```

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong

Comment: Try `as e1` and `as e2`.  As far as I know, MS Access requires the `as` for table aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
sourceDB = "C:\sourcedb.accdb"

SQL = "SELECT e1.lid " & _
      "FROM [" & sourceDB & "].[eventlog] AS e1 " & _
      "LEFT JOIN eventlog AS e2 ON e2.lid = e1.lid"
```

Comment: That was the answer I was looking.  I had my join all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have an obvious syntax error in your query: the join must be between two Tables, not the Table and Database name. Take a look at this canonical example (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198084.aspx) and correct your query correspondingly:

```
SELECT CategoryName, ProductName FROM Categories LEFT JOIN Products 
ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID;
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: That makes sense, but the join is between eventlog 1 and eventlog2.  Unless the IN statement is the wrong part?

Comment: And my IN stament was in the wrong spot.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have extended the answer. If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it accepted. Good luck with your project. Best regards,